# how to parse Json with multi-line values in scala using scala util JSON parser

Tags: json, scala

Currently I am using below code to read a config file and parse it as JSON.

```scala
val fileContent= scala.io.Source.fromFile(<file-path>)
val jsonText= fileContent.getLines.mkString("\n")
val parsedJsonText = JSON.parseFull(jsonText).get.asInstanceOf[Map[String,Any]]
```

Sample content of Json file :

```json
{ 
"hiveDB" : "db1",
"hiveTbl" : "T1",
"hiveQuery" : " select * from db2.T2 where somecol='whereCond' ",
"option" : "load"
}
```

This JSON parsing works fine for above given content of file.
However, at times *hiveQuery* Tag can have quite a big query and value of this Tag can be in multiple lines i.e. it may have newline & spread accross multiple lines before closing doble-quote("). Example:

```
"hiveQuery" : " select col1,  \\line separator 
concat_ws("-", col1, col2) as col12,   \\line separator
concat(col3,col4) as col34    \\newline separator
from db2.T3 join db4.T5 \\newline separator
on T3.col1=T5.col1"
```

While reading above formatted file, it fails during JSON parsing.

Please assist if any suitable tweaking i can do in my code.

Comment: @shahjapan please assist

Comment: What is the JSON library you are using? Most of them just ignore line breaks..

Comment: You're using the JSON parser in `scala.util`? You really shouldn't be. It was always poor quality; it was deprecated years ago; it doesn't even exist anymore in current versions of the scala-parser-combinators library.

Comment: @Seth : what is the recommended latest parser in scala library..

Comment: There are plenty and each one has pros and cons: Play JSON,  Circe, Jackson, Zio...

Answer (score 0):

One quick way would be to remove the line breaks in the first place:

Replace:

```scala
val jsonText= fileContent.getLines.mkString("\n")
```

With:

```scala
val jsonText= fileContent.getLines.mkString
```

Comment: This also I tried , but this creates additional problem with output of Json parser of format Map[String, Any] is not coming proper then and failing somewhere else.

Comment: I am using scala.util.l json parser

Comment: Explain where it fails when doing this